# Using Redundancy to Simplify Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

I came across a question which I need to solve using Redundancy:

x'z + x'y + xy'z + yz

Could anyone help me solving this? I must solve it using Redundancy only...

Comment: You must be able to use other principles than redundancy ... with redundancy alone you can't simplify this.

Comment: Then how to solve it using other principles? I'm stuck

Comment: you can take xy'z + yz and make that into (xy' + y)z (distribution), and then you can simplify xy' + y to x + y (reduction .... different instructors and different texts may use different names though). So you get (x + y)z which you can distribute back to xy + xz, and now you can combine those with x'y and x'z respectively using further laws.  What laws are available for you to use?

Comment: The questions didn't limit what laws I'm allowed to use so I guess everything is okay

Comment: Good. Interestingly, I just simplified it along the lines I suggested and never used Redundancy ...  anyway, good luck, and if you still can't figure it out ask again.

Comment: Hmm I don't quiet understand how to continue combining xy+xz with x'y and x'z.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47260/discussion-between-bram28-and-donny-avaris).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one reduction:

$$\begin{align*}
x'z+x'y+xy'z+yz&=x'y+x'z+xy'z+(x+x')yz\\
&=x'y+x'z+\color{crimson}{xy'z+xyz}+x'yz\\
&=x'y+x'z+\color{crimson}{x(y'+y)z}+x'yz\\
&=x'y+\color{blue}{x'z+xz}+x'yz\\
&=x'y+\color{blue}z+x'yz\\
&=x'(y+yz)+z\\
&=x'y+z
\end{align*}$$

Comment: does using karnaugh map will produce same answer?

Comment: @Donny: Yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

$x'z+x'y+xy'z+yz=$ (Distribution)

$x'z+x'y+(xy'+y)z=$ (Reduction)

$x'z+x'y+(x+y)z=$ (Distribution)

$x'z+x'y+xz+yz=$ (Adjacency)

$z+x'y+yz=$ (Redundancy)

$z+x'y$